# Como obter valor de uma propriedade de uma action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como faço para obter um valor de uma propriedade de uma `action`?

Comment: Propriedade seria um campo de um formulário da sua View?

Comment: Sim quero receber um valor de uma variavel que eu tenho em uma view e adicionar em outra view.

Answer (score 0):

No ASP.NET MVC voce pode usar o objeto `ViewBag` para transferir propriedades entre o controller e as views.

No controller, fica dessa forma:

```
ViewBag.Exemplo = "meu valor";
```

Voce pode acessar esse valor em qualquer arquivo de view/template que esteja sendo renderizada no momento da seguinte forma:

```
@ViewBag.Exemplo
```

Comment: agora como faco para obter um valor de uma variavel em action?

Comment: @HansMiller, sua pergunta está bem pobre em explicações... quanto mais detalhes fornecer sobre sua dúvida/problema, mais acertadas serão as respostas. Você é livre para editar a pergunta e acrescentar informações.